# Can I get my service elsewhere?

Tags: renault, service

In 2016 I bought a the new Clio GT.

Next week it should have it's annual service.

I moved to another city last month and now I am asking myself if I can get the service at any other renault dealer.

**Note:**

The car is founded and there also is an obligation (by the reseller) to take the car back after 4 years of founding (or I may keep it).

Is it "okay" or even allowed to get the service at another garage even if I may return the car where I bought it ?

**Side-Note:**

I am located in Germany.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the contract for take back or buyout specifies service then you need to follow that.

Generally, however, this just needs to be a Renault franchise service centre. They all have to adhere to specific quality defined by Renault, so they are pretty much interchangeable.

In reality, many non-franchise garages could also do the work, but you generally lose dealer warranty etc if you do that, which is why knowing a used car has a full factory service record is of high value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check my contract. I will definedly use a renault franchise service center !

Comment: I have no idea of the law in Germany but in the UK, provided that services are carried out by VAT registered garage businesses, manufacturers and the dealer network cannot shirk the warranty on the basis of service history.

Comment: Steve - yes they can. Many "Lease and Option to buy" deals in the UK require all services to be carried out by franchised garages. Some specify the actual garage, but most are fine with any tied dealership garage